# Using UI-Path studio with a proxy network

Tags: uipath-studio

I have the following problem. I try to install UI-Path studio but I cannot activate the community license due to the proxy in my company. I was searching the UI-Path docs but all I find was to edit a config file I cannot access because it is only available for the enterprise edition.
https://docs.uipath.com/robot/docs/configuring-proxy-settings-for-online-activation

I tried to edit the config file I can access in the AppData folder and added the missing fields like in the doc but this does not work as well.

````
<NSAEnabled>1</NSAEnabled>
<NSLEnabled>1</NSLEnabled>
<SecurityValue>15</SecurityValue>
<OfflineMode>0</OfflineMode>
<WorkDir>%LOCALAPPDATA%\UiPath\License</WorkDir>
<LicDir>%LOCALAPPDATA%\UiPath\License</LicDir>
<LogLevel>0</LogLevel>
<LogQLen>300</LogQLen>
<CacheQLen>25</CacheQLen>
<SoapThreadsMin>10</SoapThreadsMin>
<SoapThreadsMax>10</SoapThreadsMax>
<MaxLogSize>0</MaxLogSize>
<ProxyIP>IPv4 address</ProxyIP>
<ProxyPort>Port number</ProxyPort>
<ProxyUsername>User name</ProxyUsername>
<ProxyPassword>Password</ProxyPassword>
</SHAFERXMLParams>```

I also tried to enter the proxy address instead of my IPv4 address but this did not work too.

Is there another way how I can get the community edition up and running in my companies proxy network?

Thanks for your support
````

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have installed the enterprice version

Try to: 
1. uninstall your studio
2. download it again - https://download.uipath.com/beta/UiPathStudioSetup.exe
3. Stop your connections
4. install it again